# Circumventing PHP's max_var_lim on POST method

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I am a newbie in the PHP language and have been struggling with this particular problem.
I am trying to workaround the max_var_lim for retrieving data via POST in PHP. I am currently collecting data as follows, using a selectbox to retrieve data and putting them in an array to store in POST.  Below is the code I have in my blade.php file:

```
<form action={{route('account.confirm')}} method="POST">
    <select class="select-cats" name = "categories[]" id="optcatlist" multiple="multiple">
        @foreach ($categories as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->id}}" @if($user->company->categories->contains($cat->id)) selected="selected" @endif>
                {{$cat->name}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</form>
```

The problem is, there are a ton of options (>1000) so in the case where all are selected, I am only able to retrieve the first 1000. I am unable to change the php.ini file, so that solution is a no-go.

My question is, how do I access $_POST["categories"] on this page and implode this into a single string so I can pass it on using POST without exceeding the max_var_limit?
A detailed answer would be much appreciated as I just started using PHP and don't know left to right.
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of UI requires a user to select over 1000 options in a single select? Are you sure that the most user friendly design?? Obviously I don't really know the context but I've never seen anything with anywhere close to that number of options even on display, never mind wanting to submit them. It would likely be quite confusing/overwhelming to try and read through them and choose

Comment: @ADyson It isn't for the user, it's for the administrator to adjust specific settings for each user. A multiselect with a search box was the requested form. The problem occurs when using the select all option, or selecting a boat load of options.

Comment: Administrators are still human users and can still struggle with poorly designed UIs. Just because people request something doesn't mean that's the best solution. And you still didn't explain why there are so many options. Must be a hell of an app to have over 1000 settings available.

Comment: @ADyson My administrator is my boss and the application is a data dashboard, the options being the parameters for data (which companies data they want to see reflected). By selecting only rival companies' data, users can compare their sales to rivals. As an intern, there's not much I can do to change the design of the app, so it would be really nice if you could answer the question.

Comment: Well mainly I'm not answering because there's not really any way around the parameter restriction, unless you can get someone to change the ini file for you. That's why I'm encouraging you to consider an alternative UI approach.

Comment: @ADyson oh ok, understood. Thanks for the help. I was thinking if i could define a javascript function and post manually, then I could gather all the data currently stored in post and compress it into a long string.

Comment: Yes, you could try submitting it in JSON format